# Return non-blank rows from a range in a new range list in Excel

Tags: excel

Using Excel, assumed there is a range of data including text and number values. But some are blank rows. How could I create a range of list which only includes non-blank rows using Excel functions? Thus, I don't have to copy, paste and remove blank rows by daily.

For example, Raw data table as below,

```
AAA　111　111　111　111

BBB　111　111　111　111

AAA　111　111　111　111

CCC　111　111　111　111
QQQ　111　111　111　111     
SSS　111　111　111　111


BBB　111　111　111　111
```

Then, create a new range of table like this,

```
 AAA　111　111　111　111
 BBB　111　111　111　111
 AAA　111　111　111　111
 CCC　111　111　111　111
 QQQ　111　111　111　111
 SSS　111　111　111　111
 BBB　111　111　111　111
```

I was trying to use this formula. However, it doesn't work...

```
 {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$E$12<>"",ROW($A$1:$E$12)),ROW(F1:J1))),"")}
 {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$E$12<>"",ROW($A$1:$E$12)),ROW(F2:J2))),"")}
 {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$E$12<>"",ROW($A$1:$E$12)),ROW(F3:J3))),"")}
 {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$E$12<>"",ROW($A$1:$E$12)),ROW(F4:J4))),"")}
 {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$E$12<>"",ROW($A$1:$E$12)),ROW(F5:J5))),"")}
 {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$E$12<>"",ROW($A$1:$E$12)),ROW(F6:J6))),"")}
 {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$E$12<>"",ROW($A$1:$E$12)),ROW(F7:J7))),"")}
```

Comment: this looks fairly simple, just add a filter and sort descending/ascending

Comment: How large is your data range?

Answer (score 2):

`IF($A$1:$E$12<>"",ROW($A$1:$E$12))` in array context will result in a row vector `{1,1,1,1,1}` in case of row 1. So it always results in 5 times either the row number or `FALSE` for each row. So you will get each not empty row number 5 times.

One option would be only checking if column `A` is empty and having the array formula for each single cell instead of the single rows:

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$E$20,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$20<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$20)),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A:A))}
```

Example:

[image: Excel sheet]

Of course this is really not performant for big ranges. But I don't see another possibility using formulas.

What I would do is having a helper column using the array formula:

```
{=AND(A1:E1<>"")}
```

for each row.

[image: Sort column in excel]

And then sorting the table by this helper column descending.

Comment: No need for the helper column.  In an excel sort, blanks will sort to the bottom

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: But you will need a column to sort by. And if used any other column, the result is not as the shown expected result.

Comment: I assumed one only had to check a single column.  You are, of course, correct, if you have to check multiple columns.